# Credentials - Client ID for Web application - Invalid origin: Uses a forbidden domain

Tags: google-apps-script

We have developed an Apps Script to use the Google Web Sign in  to find out who's signed in: this project has worked in the past and still works, but occasionally Apps Script will change the JavaScript URL so we need to add this new URL to the Authorised JavaScript origins
on the Client ID for Web application URis.

All the existing URIs and any new URIs we're trying to add do not get accepted with the message:
**Invalid origin: Uses a forbidden domain**
The domain uses the following format:
https://xxxx-script.googleusercontent.com

Has something changed to stop this from working?

Comment: same problemt here would love the solution too

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered it's an issue reported to Google back in October 2020 that's not been addressed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170740549

Answer (score 0):

I was with this same problem and managed to use the picker with the getOAuthToken method instead of creating a client_id credential.

[getOAuthToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlmqX.png)

[getOAuthToken description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Df7.png)

In my case, I use React in a GAS Web App, so I removed the package that was using and created the picker manually, passing the token obtained in getOAuthToken, this is my code:

[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnyLJ.png)

[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P20cK.png)

Comment: Sorry I don't think you're talking about the same issue - the issue is we cannot add the URL required in GCP - changing the code won't affect this.

Comment: Well, I had exactly the same problem and I solved it this way.

I know that the problem in the GCP environment is a bug and should be fixed, but with this alternative I was able to use Google Picker (in my case), and I believe that the getOAuthToken method can replace the client_id flow in other cases too.